Déjà Dup unresponsive during attempted restore
I have a user with a dual-boot machine which inadvertently overwrote grub.   Using a live USB, I opened Deja-Dup to backup the user's Home directory, which was mounted to /media/ubuntu/foo/user.   I took a backup of this data.  When I attempt to restore the data, it will decrypt and I can see the folders, but manually need to select /home/user as the destination file.  When I click 'restore' the program becomes unresponsive and exits without any notification.  I've tried to restore the entire home folder, or just the /home/user/.cache folder, but both have exited with no success.   How do I probe this issue and fix it?

Not sure where it logs it's output but in a terminal run deja-dup and it will output some basic logs which might tell you why it's crashing. If not do export DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 before running. That will make deja-dup output A LOT more info.

Looks like Deja-Dup needs to also be ran from the live USB once the install has completed.  Attempting to run it from the newly-installed Linux environment causes the error.
